# set GMSAutocompleteViewController to state specific only

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, autocomplete

When i click on GMSAutocompleteViewController then it should only show all states in suggestion. I don't want city, country or anything else in this field. So is this possible?

Comment: i m not sure about the state but yeah you can filter it by country and local areas.

Comment: @MaheshDangar I want result for state... Please give any idea if you have about this...

Comment: Have you find the solution of this like only state would be filter? 
i have same requirement thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly filter state, there are some filter provided by Google Auto Complete API with their pre-defined ENUMS.

```
let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
autocompleteController.delegate = self

// Set a filter to return only addresses.
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.type = .address
autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter

present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

> **GMSAutocompleteFilter.h** : ENUMS description below

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter) {
  /**
   * All results.
   */
  kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterNoFilter,
  /**
   * Geeocoding results, as opposed to business results.
   */
  kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterGeocode,
  /**
   * Geocoding results with a precise address.
   */
  kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterAddress,
  /**
   * Business results.
   */
  kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterEstablishment,
  /**
   * Results that match the following types:
   * "locality",
   * "sublocality"
   * "postal_code",
   * "country",
   * "administrative_area_level_1",
   * "administrative_area_level_2"
   */
  kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterRegion,
  /**
   * Results that match the following types:
   * "locality",
   * "administrative_area_level_3"
   */
  kGMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilterCity,
};
```

Comment: then how can i do state filter? these are the types of filter. please add code of state filter. thanks

Comment: @YogeshPatel Hi, How we can get postal_code from the establishment ..?